# Querying Gmail API through HTTP URL

Tags: php, http, oauth, google-api-php-client, gmail-api

I want to be able to query the Gmail API through a HTTP GET request.

I'm trying to query the Gmail API to get a message unread count from my INBOX label.

API Reference : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/get

The API reference shows the following HTTP request to get the unread count.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/labels/id
```

The API reference also says you need authorization through OAuth 2.0.

I managed to get examples working in the PHP library to successfully query the API but there is not enough PHP documentation to write any specific code.

However the API reference lists all HTTP calls to access different parts of the API however I can't figure out how to use OAuth (Access Tokens) with these HTTP requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official PHP client library comes with a few examples like [this one](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/user-example.php) that shows you how to authenticate using OAuth. The [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) also has a lot of information about this process.

To get the unread messages count, you should do something like this:

```
// $googleClient is an authenticated instance of 'Google_Client'
$gmail = new \Google_Service_Gmail($googleClient);
$label = $gmail->users_labels->get('me', 'INBOX');
$unreadCount = $label->messagesUnread;
```

You might have to turn 'Conversation view' off in the Gmail settings for this to return an accurate result.

Comment: You Sir are a genius! It was difficult with lack of documentation but you've fired me in the right direction!

Comment: it's easier to look directly in the library's source code, it has a lot of comments and is well-structured

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the Gmail API in php should be similar to other Google APIs from php.  Maybe look at quickstart examples from the calendar or Google Drive APIs in PHP and work from there?

If you have the oauth2 access token you can often just put it in the "Authorization" header.  c.f. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1
Though honestly, I think it'll be a lot easier long-term to figure out how to do it with the PHP Google APIs library...